# How to execute a Pig script against multiple files within a directory

Tags: linux, hadoop, gruntjs, hive, apache-pig

Seems simple and I can easily do this in another language but I'm struggling to find the answer using Pig.  I can have one or more log files dumped to a directory daily.  I want to iteratively call each file and pass it to a Pig script for processing.  I'm aware of parameter substitution but how do I loop through the files and pass/call my Pig script?  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you write a shell script to ls the directory and call the Pig script with file name?

Answer (score 3):

You can use wildcard directly in Pig:

```
 a= load '/user/hadoop/test/*.csv' using PigStorage(',');
   dump a;
```

If your files are stored on your local drive, you need to upload them into the HDFS before :

```
hadoop fs -put /localdir/*.csv /user/hadoop/test
```

If you have to take a list of files in Pig, you can create a bash to initialise this list and call the pig command. For example, if you want to launch your pig scripts with the **5 latest files** named "httpd-.log", create a **.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
HDFS_PATH=/user/hadoop/test
FILES=`hadoop fs -ls $HDFS_PATH | grep "httpd" | sort +5 -7 | tail -5 | awk '{ print $8 }'| tr '\n' ','`
pig -f <pig_script> -p files=$FILES
```

and in your pig script :

```
a= load '$files' using PigStorage(',');
```

Romain

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure on whether it can be done directly using pig but i usually use a combination of hadoop and awk to do this

```
hadoop fs -ls /testing/*.data  | awk '{print $8}' | xargs -I {} pig -param input={} test.pig
```

In the above example assuming you have to process all the .data files under testing folder in hdfs(if you want all type then just have a *) you do a list and then grep for only the file pat part of it and then use xargs to pass it to your pig file your pig file should use input as a parameter

Pig file should have something like this

```
   a= load '$input' using PigStorage(',');
   dump a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just read the whole directory in and don't attempt to deal with individual files.

```
a= load '/user/Hadoop/test/' using PigStorage(',');
```

You will get a single relation with the contents of all the CSV files.